# table has no column named -Sqlite -android-my first app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

Yes I have read many many answers here on SO and tried all but nothing works for me. I dont know what is wrong because according to me everything looks good.

Many times I changed DB version,. Even I renamed db and table name but nothing works. I can print the log which shows the correct result but why it is not inserting into the database.

Also **When I remove all the Checkbox fields from table then data insertion works.**

**A humble request..please do not block me from asking question as this question is asked many times by others and I tried all solutions but nothing worked**.

Please guide me as I am completely new to Java and Android Studio.

Sometimes The Error is :

```
table tblCinFormNew has no column named chkbox_other
```

Sometimes The Error is :

```
table tblCinFormNew has no column named chkbox_cosmo
```

Here is my DatabaseHandler class:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbCinExtDb";

private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "tblCinFormNew";

private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";
private static final String KEY_WORK_PH_NO = "work_phone_number";
private static final String KEY_FNAME = "fname";
private static final String KEY_LNAME = "lname";
private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
private static final String KEY_STATE = "state";
private static final String KEY_ZIP = "zip";
private static final String KEY_SALOON = "chkbox_saloon";
private static final String KEY_COSMO = "chkbox_cosmo";
private static final String KEY_STUDENT = "chkbox_student";
private static final String KEY_OTHER = "chkbox_other";
private static final String KEY_ADD_INFO = "chkbox_add_info";


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT," + KEY_WORK_PH_NO + " TEXT, " + KEY_FNAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_LNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"+ KEY_CITY + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_STATE + " TEXT," + KEY_ZIP + " TEXT " + KEY_SALOON + " TEXT " + KEY_COSMO + " TEXT " + KEY_STUDENT
            + " TEXT " + KEY_OTHER + " TEXT " + KEY_ADD_INFO + " TEXT " + ")";




    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);


}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
    //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS_NEW);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}



 void addContactNew(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, contact.getEmail());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhone());
    values.put(KEY_WORK_PH_NO, contact.getWorkPhone());
    values.put(KEY_FNAME, contact.getFirstName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_LNAME, contact.getlastName());
    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, contact.getAddress());
    values.put(KEY_CITY, contact.getCity());
    values.put(KEY_STATE, contact.getState());
    values.put(KEY_ZIP, contact.getZip());
    values.put(KEY_SALOON, contact.getSaloon());
    values.put(KEY_COSMO, contact.getCosmo());
    values.put(KEY_STUDENT, contact.getStudent());
    values.put(KEY_OTHER, contact.getOther());
    values.put(KEY_ADD_INFO, contact.getAddInfo());
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}}
```

Here is my MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
            EditText phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
            EditText work_phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone1);
            EditText fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFirstName);
            EditText lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLastName);
            EditText address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);
            EditText city = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCity);
            EditText state = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextState);
            EditText zip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextZip);

            CheckBox chkSaloon =(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxSalon);
            CheckBox chkCosmo =(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxCosmetologist);
            CheckBox chkStudent = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxStudent);
            CheckBox chkOther = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxOther);
            CheckBox chkAddInfo = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxAdditionalInfo);

            String _email=email.getText().toString();
            String _phone=phone.getText().toString();
            String _work_phone=work_phone.getText().toString();
            String _fname=fname.getText().toString();
            String _lname=lname.getText().toString();

            String _address=address.getText().toString();
            String _city=city.getText().toString();
            String _state=state.getText().toString();
            String _zip=zip.getText().toString();


            String strSaloon;
            String strCosmo;
            String strStudent;
            String strOther;
            String strAdInfo;

            if(chkSaloon.isChecked()) {
                strSaloon="Salon owner";
            }
            else{
                strSaloon="Not Checked";
            }
            if(chkCosmo.isChecked()) {
                strCosmo="Licensed Cosmetologist";
            }
            else{
                strCosmo="Not Checked";
            }
            if(chkStudent.isChecked()) {
                strStudent="Student";
            }
            else{
                strStudent="Not Checked";
            }
            if(chkOther.isChecked()) {
                strOther="Other";
            }
            else{
                strOther="Not Checked";
            }
            if(chkAddInfo.isChecked()) {
                strAdInfo="Please send me additional information";
            }
            else{
                strAdInfo="Not Checked";
            }



             Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");


            db.addContactNew(new Contact(_email,_phone,_work_phone,_fname,_lname,_address,_city,_state,_zip,
                    strSaloon,strCosmo,strStudent,strOther,strAdInfo));



            // Reading all contacts
            Log.d("Reading Email",_email);
            Log.d("Reading Phone",_phone);
            Log.d("Reading Work Phone",_work_phone);
            Log.d("Reading Fname",_fname);
            Log.d("Reading Lname",_lname);
            Log.d("Reading Address",_address);
            Log.d("Reading City",_city);
            Log.d("Reading State",_state);
            Log.d("Reading Zip",_zip);
            Log.d("Reading Saloon",strSaloon);
            Log.d("Reading Cosmo",strCosmo);
            Log.d("Reading Student",strStudent);
            Log.d("Reading Other",strOther);
            Log.d("Reading AddInfo",strAdInfo);

          //  Log.d("GetContactCount",String.valueOf(db.getContactsCount()));

            Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
            List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();

            for (Contact cn : contacts) {
                String log = "Id: "+cn.getID() +" ,Name: " + cn.getFirstName() + cn.getFirstName() + " ,Saloon: " + cn.getSaloon()
                        + " ,Cosmo: " + cn.getCosmo();
                // Writing Contacts to log
                Log.d("Name: ", log);
            }
        }
    });





}
```

}

Here is my Contact.java Constructor

```
public class Contact {
int id;
String email;
String phone;
String workPhone;
String firstName;
String lastName;
String address;
String city;
String state;
String zip;
String chkSalon;
String chkCosmo;
String chkStudent;
String chkOther;
String chkAddInfo;


public Contact()
{
    // Empty Constructor
}
public Contact(int id, String email, String phone, String workPhone,String firstName,
               String lastName, String address,String city , String state,String zip, String chkSalon,
               String chkCosmo, String chkStudent, String chkOther,String chkAddInfo
){
    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.workPhone=workPhone;
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.lastName=lastName;
    this.address=address;
    this.city=city;
    this.state=state;
    this.zip=zip;
    this.chkSalon=chkSalon;
    this.chkCosmo=chkCosmo;
    this.chkStudent=chkStudent;
    this.chkOther=chkOther;
    this.chkAddInfo=chkAddInfo;


}

// constructor
public Contact(String email, String phone, String workPhone,String firstName,
               String lastName, String address,String city , String state,String zip, String chkSalon,
               String chkCosmo, String chkStudent, String chkOther,String chkAddInfo
              ){

    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.workPhone=workPhone;
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.lastName=lastName;
    this.address=address;
    this.city=city;
    this.state=state;
    this.zip=zip;
    this.chkSalon=chkSalon;
    this.chkCosmo=chkCosmo;
    this.chkStudent=chkStudent;
    this.chkOther=chkOther;
    this.chkAddInfo=chkAddInfo;

}
// getting ID
public int getID(){
    return this.id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int id){
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPhone(){
    return this.phone;
}


public void setPhone(String phone){
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getWorkPhone(){
    return this.workPhone;
}


public void setWorkPhone(String workPhone){
    this.workPhone = workPhone;
}

public String getEmail(){
    return this.email ;
}


public void setEmail(String email){
    this.email = email;
}




public String getFirstName(){
    return this.firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName){
    this.firstName=firstName;
}

public String getlastName(){
    return this.lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName){
    this.lastName=lastName;
}



public void setAddress(String address){
    this.address=address;
}

public String getAddress(){
    return this.address;
}

public String getCity(){
    return this.city;
}

public void setCity(String city){
    this.city=city;
}
public String getState(){
    return this.state;
}

public void setState(String state){
    this.state=state;
}
public String getZip(){ return this.zip; }

public void setZip(String zip){
    this.zip=zip;
}

 public void setSaloon(String chkSalon){
    this.chkSalon=chkSalon ;
}

public String getSaloon(){  return this.chkSalon; }



public String getCosmo(){ return this.chkCosmo;}
public void setCosmo(String chkCosmo){
    this.chkCosmo=chkCosmo ;
}

public String getStudent(){
    return this.chkStudent;
}
public void setStudent(String chkStudent){
    this.chkStudent=chkStudent ;
}

public String getOther(){
    return this.chkOther;
}
public void setOther(String chkOther){
    this.chkOther=chkOther ;
}

public String getAddInfo(){
    return this.chkAddInfo;
}
public void setAddInfo(String chkAddInfo){
    this.chkAddInfo=chkAddInfo ;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing **comma(,)** after "TEXT" in your CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE query

KEY_ZIP + **" TEXT "** + KEY_SALOON + **" TEXT "** + KEY_COSMO + **" TEXT "** + KEY_STUDENT
            + **" TEXT "** + KEY_OTHER + **" TEXT "** + KEY_ADD_INFO + " TEXT "

Try after doing this change. It should work, and if you still get this error, check your table structure using Android Device Monitor if you are using emulator and debug your code.

Comment: You are my hero!! Thanks a lot Ankur for pointing out the problem and I missed :D. Btw I tried ADM also but it shows blank under folders and no data path. Also I executed shell script on my local computer adm but it says everytime Permission Denied.